# How to find the missing dates within a date range from a table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I want to perform some kind of analysis on the missing data loads from our Azure Synapse tables.
For example, I have a table named Customers

```
sno  load_date      column1     column2     column3     column4
1    01-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
2    02-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
3    03-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
4    04-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
5    07-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
6    09-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
7    10-11-2021      value1     value2      value3      value4
```

Now, I want to extract a list of all the load_date entries from a date range that are missing from this table.

So, my expected output would be as follows:

```
missing_load_dates
05-11-2021
06-11-2021
08-11-2021
```

I want to scale this across my database as I have hundreds of tables and millions of records in each table.

How to achieve this in SQL?

Comment: usually such queries are created using calendar table

Comment: There are loads of examples of how to solve this available with a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Create a calendar/sequence table containing all dates which you expect to be in your current table.  Then left join this calendar table to your current table to find the missing dates.

```sql
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '20211101' AS [date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
    FROM dates
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20211110'
)

SELECT d.date
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.load_date = d.date
WHERE t.load_date IS NULL
ORDER BY d.date;
```

You may change the date range in the calendar CTE above to whatever values you need.

Comment: Surely you have answered this before and can flag as a duplicate? :)

Comment: @DaleK If you have an exact duplicate, then go ahead and hammer it closed.  The SQL Server calendar table question I found on SO was a bit rough around the edges.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it asked so many times, but didn't save any of the links.